# Conversion of df one column values to multiple column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatables, pivot

| id | date | decision |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-10 | improve |
| 1 | 2022-11-10 | checked |
| 2 | 2021-09-12 | checked |
| 3 | 2020-08-22 | checked |
| 4 | 2019-11-10 | complete |
| 4 | 2019-11-10 | revise |

Converting above dataframe as

| id | date | CR | Principal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-10 | checked | improve |
| 2 | 2021-09-12 | checked | NA |
| 3 | 2020-08-22 | checked | NA |
| 4 | 2019-11-10 | revise | complete |

Comment: Can you explain logic?

Comment: Id and date column should be unique, i.e., one row for each id. If there are two decisions for single id then convert the decisions into CR and Principal where CR is the last decision and Principal is the first decision.

Comment: Whats happens if there are 3 or more decisions?

Comment: Then it should create new column and respective value. Maximum is 4 decisions.

Comment: Reopened, more complicated like only `cumcount` + `pivot`.

Comment: If 3 and 4 decisions are empty display null values for each id so that rename(columns={0:'CR',1:'Principal', 2:"NA",3:"NA"}

Comment: Rather not, because get duplicated columns names, so if select `print (df['NA'])` get both columns.

Comment: 3 and 4 are not duplicates. 3 is final 4 is post final. They should display nan if not present in df.

Comment: fillna(0) and display final and post final columns as well in df while printing df

Comment: Added `fillna(0)` to answer.

Comment: In your answer df has only 4 columns, but required final and postfinal columns with values as zero as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False` for counter in descending order and pivoting by 4 columns, then use `rename` - add keys to dictionary for rename if 3 or 4 duplicated decisions:

```
df = (df.assign(g = df.groupby(['id','date']).cumcount(ascending=False))
        .pivot(['id','date'], 'g', 'decision')
        .reindex(columns=range(4))
        .fillna(0)
        .rename(columns={0:'CR',1:'Principal',2:'final',3:'post final'})
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   id        date       CR Principal  final  post final
0   1  2022-11-10  checked   improve    0.0         0.0
1   2  2021-09-12  checked         0    0.0         0.0
2   3  2020-08-22  checked         0    0.0         0.0
3   4  2019-11-10   revise  complete    0.0         0.0
```